# Binding within a control template

Tags: wpf

I have the following template defined. The TextBlock PART_TextBlock binds correctly if outside of the StackPanel but when placed inside the StackPanel I get a binding error. The StackPanel datacontext is bound to a converter and is applying the storyboard (flashing tab) as required. I need the tab to flash and also the text to display in the tab header with the flashing in the background of the text.

```
                <dashboard:EditableTabHeaderControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dashboard:EditableTabHeaderControl}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel  DataContext="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DependencyObjectToFilterConverter}}" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" >
                                <StackPanel.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasError}" Value="True" >
                                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking" >
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation 
                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"

                                                      To="Red"
                                                      Duration="00:00:00.4"
                                                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                      AutoReverse="True"  />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasError}" Value="False" >
                                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking" />
                                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                                            </DataTrigger>

                                        </Style.Triggers>

                                    </Style>

                                </StackPanel.Style>

                                <TextBlock Text=" " VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TabHeader" Text="{Binding Path=Title,
                                    Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                </TextBox>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Title,
                                    Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" >
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <!-- IF THE TEXBOX/TEXTBLOCK ARE PLACED HERE TITLE BINDS CORRECTLY-->

                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_TabHeader" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger.Setters>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </dashboard:EditableTabHeaderControl.Template>
            </dashboard:EditableTabHeaderControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the Binding expression, the following worked

Text="{Binding DataContext.Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=dashboard:EditableTabHeaderControl}}"